# How to detect if any keyboard key other than a specific keyboard key has been pressed in C++?

Tags: c++, keyboard-input

I have the following code which works fine.

```
int x = 0;
int main()
{    
    while(true) {   
        if (GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000 && x == 0) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (GetKeyState('B') & 0x8000 && x == 1) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (GetKeyState('C') & 0x8000 && x == 2) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 0;
            //Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

In order to execute the `//Do Something` part of the code, the user must first press `A`, then `B` and then `C` in that order. However the user can press any key in between and it will still work. So in addition to "`A`+`B`+`C`" the following will also work.

1. `A`+`C`+`B`+`C`
2. `A`+`Q`+`B`+`C`
3. `A`+`F11`+`B`+`8`+`LSHIFT`+`Spacebar`+`Tab`+`C`

I want only the `A`+`B`+`C` combination to work. Not any of the above.

The code I am trying to implement is somewhat like this

```
int x = 0;
int main()
{
    while(true) {

        if (GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000 && x == 0) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 1;
        }
        else if (GetKeyState('B') & 0x8000 && x == 1) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 2;
        }
        else if (GetKeyState(/*Any keyboard input other than 'B' or 'A'*/) & 0x8000 && x == 1) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 0;
        }
        else if (GetKeyState('C') & 0x8000 && x == 2) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 0;
            //Do Something
        }
        else if (GetKeyState(/*Any keyboard input other than 'C' or 'B'*/) & 0x8000 && x == 2) {
            Sleep(500);
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So you see I understand the logic required. I just don't know the correct code required to replace the commented part of my code. Please note that the reason I have entered two keys in the comments is because the user might accidentally press a key twice or thrice for which he/she needs to be excused and code needs to still work.

I think I have tried my best to make this question as understandable as possible. If not feel free to suggest edits.

Comment: What is `GetKeyState`?

Comment: Can't you use a state machine or two boolean flags that get enabled sequentially as `'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'` are pressed respectively?

Comment: What do you think x == 1 (or 0 or 2) in if statements do? What are they used for? I think when you answer my question, you will get one step closer to find answer to your own question. :]

Comment: You meant to use just a plain else {} clause at the end.  GetKeyState() is not suitable for use in a console mode app, it is synchronous with the message queue and a console mode app doesn't have one.  Do it correctly, without the Sleep calls, with ReadConsoleInput().

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, for simplicity, you could use [_kbhit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58w7c94c.aspx) unless there is a specific reason you want to use `GetKeyState`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>  

int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!_kbhit())
            continue;

        switch (_getch())
        {
        case 'A':
            x == 0 ? ++x : x = 0;
            break;
        case 'B':
            x == 1 ? ++x : x = 0;
            break;
        case 'C':
            x == 2 ? ++x : x = 0;
            break;
        default:
            x = 0;
        }

        if (x == 0)
            std::cout << "Oops!" << std::endl;
        else if (x == 3)
        {
            std::cout << "Bingo!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```